# How to capture show-paren-mode region into the kill ring?

Tags: kill-ring, balanced-parentheses

I'm enjoying `show-paren-mode` using the "expression" style, which highlights a parenthesized region in a contrasting color.  I'd like to define an Emacs Lisp function that could capture the region into the kill ring, as in `M-w` (`kill-ring-save`), but the region seems to be represented as an "overlay," and there is no function to capture it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- If your cursor is after the closing paren: **`M-- C-M-SPC`**
- If your cursor is before the opening paren: **`C-M-SPC`**

`C-M-SPC` is bound by default to **`mark-sexp`**.  It selects the next *N* sexps.  With a negative prefix arg it selects the previous abs(*N*) sexps.

(Oh, and it doesn't matter whether `show-paren-mode` is on or off.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the source, I came up with this function:

`(defun kill-ring-save-paren-overlay ()
    "Save the current 'show-paren-mode' overlay into the kill rang"
  (interactive)
  (if (and (boundp 'show-paren--overlay) (overlay-end show-paren--overlay))
      (kill-ring-save (overlay-start show-paren--overlay)
                      (overlay-end show-paren--overlay))
    (user-error "No parentheses are being shown right now")))`